# Why isn't plt.annotate() placing the text exactly at the origin in polar coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following code to place a number at the origin of the plot (0,0).

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="polar")

plt.annotate("3", 
            xy=(0, 0),
            fontsize=20, color="#000",
            ha='center', va='center'
            )

plt.show()
```

As you can see the number 3 is not vertically at the center, the horizontal alignment is correct. - [image]

What I am doing wrong? I tried va='center_baseline' as well, in that case, the text shows at the center but the bbox is slightly below the center.
Here is the code-

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="polar")

plt.annotate("3", 
            xy=(0, 0),
            fontsize=20, color="#fff",
            bbox=dict(boxstyle="circle", facecolor="black", linewidth=2.0,),
            ha='center', va='center_baseline'
            )

plt.show()
```

Here is the result - [image]

I want the bbox and text align exactly at the origin.